# How to get multiple rows of data into a chart with Javascript

Tags: javascript, sql

I am having trouble figuring out how to get multiple rows of SQL data into my Google Chart.

I have gotten as far as writing the data to the console (commented out below), but how do I write the google chart code so that it writes a new array for each row in my table?

For example I want the following code to be repeated for each row in my data:

```
[''+bridge_id_grab, +milemarker_grab, 0, '1', +bridge_health_grab]
```

Full Code:

```
var sql_statement3 = "SELECT bridge_id, bridge_health, milemarker FROM TABLE_NAME &api_key=MY_API_KEY&callback=?"
    $.getJSON('https://MY_USERNAME.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql/?q='+sql_statement3, function(data) {
      //console.log(data.rows);
      $.each(data.rows, function(key, val) {          
             for (i in data.rows) {             
                    var bridge_id_grab = [];                        
                    var bridge_health_grab = [];                        
                    var milemarker_grab = [];                       

                    bridge_id_grab.push(data.rows[i].bridge_id);                    
                    bridge_health_grab.push(data.rows[i].bridge_health);                    
                    milemarker_grab.push(data.rows[i].milemarker);  

                    //console.log(bridge_id_grab);
                    //console.log(bridge_health_grab);
                    //console.log(milemarker_grab);     

                     function corridor_chart() {

                            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                                    ['Bridge', 'MileMarker', '', '', 'Health'],
                                    [''+bridge_id_grab,    +milemarker_grab,     0,      '1',  +bridge_health_grab],
                                    [''+bridge_id_grab,    +milemarker_grab,     0,      '2',  +bridge_health_grab]
                            ]);

                              var options = {
                               "width": "100%",
                                            "legacyContinuousAxisRemoved": true,
                                            "chartArea": {
                                                "top": "0%",
                                                "left": "0%",
                                                "right": "0%",
                                                "width": "100%",
                                                "height": "80%"
                                            },
                                            "height": 180,
                                            "legend": "bottom",
                               title: '',
                               colors: ['#DB0000', '#FF0400', '#FF5500','#FF7C30', '#FFC431', '#FFF428', '#DCEA26', '#A7ED25', '#5DE207', '#00D300'],
                               "hAxis": {
                                 "useFormatFromData": true,
                                 "formatOptions": {},
                                 "textStyle": {
                                    "color": "none",
                                    "fontSize": 0
                                 },
                                 "viewWindow": {},
                                 "gridlines": {
                                    "color": "none",
                                    "count": "-1"
                                 },
                                 "titleTextStyle": {
                                    "color": "none",
                                    "fontSize": 0
                                 }
                              },
                                vAxis: {
                                title: "",
                                "gridlines": {
                                    "color": "none",
                                    "count": "0"
                                 },},
                                "bubble": {
                                 "textStyle": {
                                    "color": "blue",
                                    "fontSize": 11
                                 },
                                 "opacity": "1",
                                 "stroke": "#ffffff"
                              },
                              };

                              var chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('corridor_chart'));
                              chart.draw(data, options);
                            }

                            google.setOnLoadCallback(corridor_chart);                       
                }
            });
        });
```

Edited code based on darrylivan's answer & comments (It's working, although I am still getting an error: 'Uncaught Error: Not an array'):

```
  var sql_statement3 = "SELECT bridge_id, bridge_health, milemarker FROM TABLE_NAME &api_key=MY_API_KEY&callback=?"
       $.getJSON('https://MY_USERNAME.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql/?q='+sql_statement3, function(data) {
                google.load('visualization', '1.0',  { 'packages': ['corechart', 'controls', 'bar'] });

                var chartData = [];
                chartData.push(  ['Bridge', 'MileMarker', '', '', 'Health'] )

                 for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) 
                    {
                       var row = data.rows[i];
                       var dataRow = [ 
                          row.bridge_id.toString(), 
                          row.milemarker,
                          0, 
                          row.bridge_id.toString(),
                          row.bridge_health
                          ];

                        chartData.push( dataRow );
                        console.log(dataRow);
                    }

                    /* then call your charting func, but pass in the data
                      instead of computing it in that func.
                      */
                    corridor_chart( chartData );

                    function corridor_chart(chartData) {

                            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);

                              var options = {
                               "width": "100%",
                                            "legacyContinuousAxisRemoved": true,
                                            "chartArea": {
                                                "top": "0%",
                                                "left": "0%",
                                                "right": "0%",
                                                "width": "100%",
                                                "height": "80%"
                                            },
                                            "height": 180,
                               title: '',
                                            "legend": "bottom",
                               colors: ['#DB0000', '#FF0400', '#FF5500','#FF7C30', '#FFC431', '#FFF428', '#DCEA26', '#A7ED25', '#5DE207', '#00D300'],
                               "hAxis": {
                                 "useFormatFromData": true,
                                 "formatOptions": {},
                                 "textStyle": {
                                    "color": "none",
                                    "fontSize": 0
                                 },
                                 "viewWindow": {},
                                 "gridlines": {
                                    "color": "none",
                                    "count": "-1"
                                 },
                                 "titleTextStyle": {
                                    "color": "none",
                                    "fontSize": 0
                                 }
                              },
                                vAxis: {
                                title: "",
                                "gridlines": {
                                    "color": "none",
                                    "count": "0"
                                 },},
                                "bubble": {
                                 "textStyle": {
                                    "color": "blue",
                                    "fontSize": 11
                                 },
                                 "opacity": "1",
                                 "stroke": "#ffffff"
                              },
                              };

                              var chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('corridor_chart'));
                              chart.draw(data, options);
                            }
                            google.setOnLoadCallback(corridor_chart);   
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you need to build up an array of data into a variable, and then use that variable in your chart option definition.

So, I am going to assume you have an array of json objects (maybe right, maybe not depending on how that data is returned, but it is likely...)

```
var sql_statement3 = "SELECT bridge_id, bridge_health, milemarker FROM TABLE_NAME &api_key=MY_API_KEY&callback=?";


$.getJSON('https://MY_USERNAME.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql/?q='+sql_statement3, function(data) {

// initialize your array
var chartData = [];

chartData.push(  ['Bridge', 'MileMarker', '', '', 'Health'] )


/* loop over sql data, and populate array
   you can be more compact about this, but
   this is a bit more readable...
*/
for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) 
{
   var row = data.rows[i];
   console.log ( row);
   var dataRow = [ 
      row.bridge_id, 
      row.milemarker,
      0, 
      i.toString(),
      row.bridge_health
      ];

   chartData.push( dataRow );

}

/* then call your charting func, but pass in the data
  instead of computing it in that func.
  */
corridor_chart( chartData );

}

function corridor_chart( data ) {

  // don't compute data in here - it is passed in.
  //  ...


}
```

As an aside:

You only need one iterative loop to build up this array - not both:

```
 $each(data.rows...) //   --OR--
 for (i in data.rows)
```

Also - if your data s returned in an array, you probably want to use

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) .
```

If your data is returned as an object, then your proposed method is hunky dory:

```
  for (row in data.rows)
```

This latter iterative loop is really intended for iterating over objects.

Comment: Thanks - this is really helpful. I have tried this out and I am getting errors with the Google chart... how do I get the passed in data assigned to the chart? I tried this: "var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();"  See edited question above for my current code... still not working for me and not sure why.

Comment: I am getting an error - 'Table has no columns' when trying to use 'var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(data);'

Comment: I might not be understanding, but from your original code (copied from an example?), it looks like you need to instantiate the chart with the div:  `var chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('corridor_chart'));` and then draw the chart with the data and the options:  `                          chart.draw(data, options);' ` .  So, you don't pass the data in until you do the `draw()` method.  But - maybe I am not understanding the question...

Comment: Yes that is correct - and I tried doing that, but I get a different error: 'You called the draw() method with an Array rather than a DataTable or DataView', which is why I tried adding: 'var data = new google.visualization.DataTable()'

Comment: Maybe you need to call the `var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable( data )` first - turning the array into a data table, then you can call the `chart.draw( dataTable, options )` .  I don't have expert knowledge in the google charting, but from you original code, that looks like it might work...

Comment: Okay well tried that and now getting error: 'Column 0 must be of type string'. How would I change the column type??

Comment: you can call `toString()` on anything, or in this case, when you are building your array from the data,  you might have ` var dataRow = [       row.bridge_id.toString(),       row.milemarker,       0,       i.toString(),       row.bridge_health       ];`  .  Note the change from `row.bridge_id` to `row.bridge_id.toString()`.

Comment: I tried this and get another error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null'

Comment: Gotcha.  Try sending the row variable to the console to see what you really have in there before you try to use it.  Edit above...

Comment: If it is not obvious what is going wrong on seeing the debug, you could past it here.  Seems like you must have a null or undefined value for bridge_id column in your Db for at least one row.

Comment: Okay I did some fiddling and got it working. Passed chartData instead of data and that did it. I also deleted blank rows in my database and that solved the 'toString()' issue. It's working now, but shows an error in the console: 'Uncaught Error: Not an array' referring to this line: 'var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);' I will post my full code above.

Comment: darn, I am not sure on that one.  it might be that the initial row in the data for labeling the chart is not composed correctly?  The example google puts forward has a slightly different format using an array of objects that describe the data (see this helptile if you want:  http://helptile.com/fs/930 ).

Comment: I figured out that passing that variable into the function: 'function corridor_chart(chartData)' was actually causing the issue. Solved. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Great!  Glad you figured it out!